# How to use javascript to extract an SVG map from a server

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I am helping someone figure out how to use javascript to extract a map in an SVG format. I am wondering if there is a way to do this without saving the map image as a jpeg file or any other image file.

Answer (score 0):

If its a one off, you could just alert/log the element and copy/paste it. Eg (use a more specific id or dom selector if there is more than one svg)

```
alert( document.querySelectorAll('svg')[0].outerHTML );
```